# Extra Column in self-referencing model

Tags: go, join, go-gorm

I just started to use Gorm and I am encountering troubles to define a model.
I have succeeded in creating a join table by following the doc example for self-referencing model:

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Friends []*User `gorm:"many2many:friendships;association_jointable_foreignkey:friend_id"`
}
```

The problem is I want an extra column in my join table to know whether a friend is accepted or not. I have looked for an answer through the internet but the only answer that I found is this : 
https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/719#issuecomment-168485989
but I don't understand how I can adapt it in my case.
If anyone out there has any examples and/or solutions, I will be grateful.
Thanks again !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867621/gorm-grails-add-extra-column-to-a-jointable-expression

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear but it's not the same ORM than the one used in Grail

Comment: Sorry for that. I don't think you can add extra column in `Gorm`.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/788jmi/in_gorm_is_it_possible_to_define_an_extra_column/

Comment: I already saw that but I have a hard time to create the join table struct. I am currently trying to follow the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105380/define-associative-model-in-golang-gorm. If I find a workaround, I'll post the answer here

Answer (score 1):

This answer is 4 years late but I had the same issue today so hope this helps anyone.

To add an extra column to a join table created by a self-referencing many-to-many relationship in GORM, you need to create a custom join table. In this post's case, the models would look like this:

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Friends []*User `gorm:"many2many:friends"`
}

// custom join table
type Friend struct {
    UserId   int `gorm:"primary_key"`
    FriendId int `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Accepted bool
}
```

Then, you use the **SetupJoinTable** method **BEFORE** you use the **AutoMigrate** method. This wasn't working for me until I called the join method prior to the migrate method:

```
err := db.SetupJoinTable(&User{}, "Friends", &Friendship{})
err = db.AutoMigrate(&User{})
```

This should create the join table with the extra column.

Hope this helped!